# Properly Setting an instance of a COM Object in C#

Tags: c#, com

I have a VB based block of code I need to rewrite in C# and I'm writing a function which creates an instance of a COM object and creates a new terminal session, goes out, reads a screen and returns the contents of the screen. Right now though I feel like I'm not taking the right approach in C# and would appreciate some feedback.

**VB Code**

```
set bzlipi = CreateObject("BlueZone.LIPI")
bzlipi.Username = "myuserid"
bzlipi.Password = "mypassword"
bzlipi.HostAddress = "101.122.0.138"
bzlipi.ShowTransferStatusWindow = False
bzlipi.LocalPromptBeforeOverwrite = False
result = bzlipi.ReceiveFile( "local.txt", "MYLIB/F4101" )
MsgBox bzlipi.ErrorMessage
```

**C#**

```
    using BZLIPILib;
    using BZWHLLLib;

    public void Connector() {
    object Host = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("BZLIPILib.LIPI"));
    //Set Host properties
    }
```

As it stands, this is not not recognizing any properties within Host as its
 VB counterpart does above. I've made all the available COM object
 references within package manager of my VS project.  What should I be
 doing differently?

Comment: Is there a reason for not referencing the library directly?

Comment: No real reason other than what the vendor recommended doing.

Comment: The C# code in fact *does* reference the library directly, that's why the `using` directives work.  Not actually using it is, well, unwise.  But requires `dynamic Host` and `Type.GetTypeFromProgID("BlueZone.LIPI")`.  IntelliSense still won't show members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
using BZLIPILib;
using BZWHLLLib;
...
object Host = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("BZLIPILib.LIPI"));
```

...to:

```
using BZLIPILib;
using BZWHLLLib;
...

LIPI Host = new LIPI();
```

...then intellisense will work as expected.

**Update:**  It appears that the actual code required is:

```
using BZLIPILib;
using BZWHLLLib;
...

LipiObj Host = new LipiObj();
```

...as per OP's comment below.

Comment: You were mostly right! Its actually LipiObj Host = new LipiObj();

Comment: @LifeOf0sAnd1s Oh!  Wonder why `CreateObject("BlueZone.LIPI")` worked?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm running into a lot is issues because all of these are embedded in old Auto Hot Key objects with VB6